# how to manipulate a string variable in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have one label for which value is coming from an array. I want to use that name for giving id ti my label. Below is the code for that.

`<label htmlFor={name}><b>{ name }</b> </label>`

How can I covert it to lower case and remove the spaces in between of it so that I can have proper id in html. I am looking somewhat like below.

`<label htmlFor={name}.trim().toLowerCase()><b>{ name }</b> </label>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular JavaScript expressions go **between** `{` and `}` in JSX, not just variable names.

```
htmlFor={ name.trim().toLowerCase() }
```

Note that `trim` only removes spaces at the start and end of a string, not in the middle.

Comment: how to remove it from middle as well. I would need without space. Or is it fine if I have control id with space in that.